# unpickle instance after refactoring module name

Tags: python, module, pickle

Previously I defined an `ElectrodePositionsModel` class in the module `gselu.py` in the package `gselu`, and pickled the ElectrodePositionsModel objects into some files.

Some time later it was decided to refactor the project and the package name `gselu` was changed to `ielu`

When I attempt to unpickle the old pickle files with `pickle.load()`, the process fails with the error, 'module' object has no attribute 'ElectrodePositionsModel'. What I understand of the `Unpickler`s behavior is that this is because the pickle thinks it has stored an instance of `gselu.gselu.ElectrodePositionsModel`, and tries to therefore import this class from this module. When it doesn't exist, it gives up.

I think that I am supposed to add something to the module's **init**.py to tell it where the `gselu.gselu.ElectrodePositionsModel` is, but I can't get the `pickle.load()` function to give me any error message other than `'module' has no attribute 'ElectrodePositionsModel'` and I can't figure out where I am supposed to provide the correct path to find it. The code that does the unpickling is in the same module file (`gselu.py`) as the `ElectrodePositionsModel` class.

When I load the pickle file in an ipython session and manually import ElectrodePositionsModel, it loads correctly.

How do I tell the pickler where to load this module?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this questions is old, but I just ran into a similar problem.

What I did to solve it was to take the old code and unpickle the data using that.
Then instead of pickling directly the custom classes, I pickled `CustomClass.__dict__` which only contained raw python.
This data could then easily be imported in the new module by doing

```
a = NewNameOfCustomClass()
a.__dict__ = pickle.load('olddata.p', 'rb')
```

This method works if your custom class only has standard variables (such as builtins or numpy arrays, etc).